# using encoding plugin in message template Solspace friends throws error, hope for a solution

Tags: solspace, solspace-friends, encryption

When using this plugin http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/basee64 inside a Solspace Friends Message Template I get PHP errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: EE::$TMPL

Filename: basee64/pi.basee64.php

Line Number: 36

and

---
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: basee64/pi.basee64.php
---
```

What I try to do is to encode the username in the message. So, when clicking the link, the encoded username must be decoded in the redirect/return/ template.
(The plugin works OK in this Template on its own)

The message IS send allright, but the plugin fails. Probably a parse order? I hope someone reacts with an idea how to make this work.

Code in my Solspace friends Message Template where I create the encoded return URL:

```
{path="redirect/return/"}/{friends_message_id}/{exp:basee64:encode parse="inward"}{friends_recipient_username}{/exp:basee64:encode}
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends notification templates have certain limitations, and except for a few very early parsed variables (eg. segments) and embeds, EE tags, which include 3rd-party tags, do not parse in these special templates (EE code in embeds also don't parse). What parses are the Friends variables available in the notification, and described in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. We will try with an embed or snippet. This might solve another -related- issue. I'll come back here to report later, in case others look for the same.

Comment: Like I said, whatever EE tags are within the embed will _also_ not work.